# How to only return the embedded objects from a document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following model...

```
{
    username: 'bob',
    data: [
        {
            sport: 'football',
            events: [
                {
                    event: 1,
                    _id: 'h4jh234ht34j'
                },
                {
                    event: 2,
                    _id: '4h326ol2j3ld'
                },
                {
                    event: 2,
                    _id: 'fdsfasdfa3ws'
                }
                // ... more events
            ]
        },
        {
            sport: 'cricket',
            events: [
                {
                    event: 3,
                    _id: 'hd2g234ht3gj'
                },
                {
                    event: 2,
                    _id: '33326oldwqld'
                },
                {
                    event: 6,
                    _id: '461fa24gsa3s'
                }
                // ... more events
            ]
        },
        // ... more sports
    ]
}
```

Is there a way I can query this database to find any event objects where the event property equals 2? I want the query to return an array of objects for all the events from the different collections where the event = 2. Is this possible, or does the events array need to be an immediate ancestor of the "data" property?

Comment: Do you want the whole "bob" user document or just the events?

Comment: just the events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the whole user document that contains some id you can do it just like this [Playground 1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uRPeC0OeaOd)

If you just want the matched events you could do it with $unwinds. [Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9JtmZHzfp3l)

Finally is you just want the event data, you could use $replaceRoot to get your expected result. [Playground 3](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zNImNxVTve2)

Comment: Thank you, but although the model is what I want for the 2nd playground, the query returns the entire document when an object matches, but I only want it to return the object

Comment: @willmahon Edited with a 3rd playground just with the events info.